# Labeling into Bars in Barchart with pyplot and Pandas fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, label, bar-chart

My aim is to create a barchart and annotate the bars by inserting in them the value they correspond to.

Something is going wrong with my code but I don't know what:

My data:

```
top_15

         Total
Country 
China   228100
India   183289
Pakistan    92869
Philippines 81537
United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland    60356
Republic of Korea   49094
Iran (Islamic Republic of)  45713
United States of America    38151
Sri Lanka   35156
Romania 33823
Russian Federation  28283
France  25550
Afghanistan 21941
Ukraine 21113
Morocco 21092
```

My code:

```
top_15.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(10, 10), color='steelblue')
plt.xlabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.title('Top 15 Conuntries Contributing to the Immigration to Canada between 1980 - 2013')

# annotate value labels to each country
for index, value in enumerate(top_15.loc[:,'Total']): 
    label = format(int(value), ',') # format int with commas

    # place text at the end of bar (subtracting 47000 from x, and 0.1 from y to make it fit within the bar)
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(value - 47000, index - 0.10), color='white')

plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you were looking for, but try changing the line:

`plt.annotate(label, xy=(value - 47000, index - 0.10), color='white')`

to:

`plt.text(value, index, label, ha='right', va='center')`

Answer (score 0):

You can decide the position of the annotation with `xy`. You are setting different values for each country with `value - 47000`. This bring to have also some negative values(outside the graph). To show all of them in the beginning of the bar you can use a fixed value for example:

```
xy=(1000, index - 0.10)
```

Or a value which is bigger than the smallest one(in this case it will be at the end of the bar):

```
 xy=(value - 21000, index - 0.10)
```

Comment: @user8270077 You are welcome. Dont forget to upvote the answers that you found useful and accept the one that you think is the best. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the x value that you are subtracting i.e. 47000(it's greater than the smallest value), just reduce that number to 47(or any number bigger than the smallest value) and it will work. Also change the color of text black if you have a white background

```
% %matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
top_15.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(10, 10), color='steelblue')
plt.xlabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.title('Top 15 Conuntries Contributing to the Immigration to Canada between 1980 - 2013')

# annotate value labels to each country
for index, value in enumerate(top_15.loc[:,'Total']): 
    label = format(int(value), ',') # format int with commas

    # place text at the end of bar (subtracting 47000 from x, and 0.1 from y to make it fit within the bar)
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(value - 47, index - 0.10), color='black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Alternate Approach:**

```
% matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(15,10),color="steelblue", fontsize=13);

ax.set_title("Top 15 Conuntries Contributing to the Immigration to Canada between 1980 - 2013", fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel("Number of Immigrants", fontsize=18);

for i in ax.patches:
    # get_width pulls left or right; get_y pushes up or down
    ax.text(i.get_width()+.1, i.get_y()+.31, \
            str(round((i.get_width()), 2)), fontsize=10, color='black')
```

Comment: Can you upvote if you think this will help others and worth it?